# Using an image with listItemLockup

Tags: tvos, tvml

I'd like to replace the text description with an image I created, so instead of this:

```
<listItemLockup>
            <title>TITLE</title>
            <decorationLabel>7</decorationLabel>
                <relatedContent>
                    <grid>
                        <section>
                            <lockup ......
                            </lockup>

                        </section>
                     </grid>
                </relatedContent>
</listItemLockup>
```

I've tried this:

```
<listItemLockup>
            <decorationImage src="Path to image here" />
            <decorationLabel>7</decorationLabel>
                <relatedContent>
                    <grid>
                        <section>
                            <lockup ......
                            </lockup>

                        </section>
                     </grid>
                </relatedContent>
</listItemLockup>
```

This doesn't work. Am I just misunderstanding the use of images within listItemLockup or am I missing something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the [Apple Tv Markup Language Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/ATV_Template_Guide/LockupElements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015064-CH10-SW5), you can add an `<img>` component inside a `listItemLockup`, so it will be:

```
<listItemLockup>
  <img src="Path to the image" width="20" height="20"/>
  <decorationLabel>7</decorationLabel>
  <relatedContent>
     <grid>
        <section>
           <lockup ......
           </lockup>
         </section>
      </grid>
   </relatedContent>
</listItemLockup>
```